# Create node cluster's focal points by data attribute in d3?

Tags: d3.js, cluster-computing, nodes, force-layout

I'm trying to force nodes into different clusters in force layout based on a certain attribute in the data like "group." I'm adapting the code from Mike Bostock's multi foci force layout example ([code](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1021953), [example](http://static.cybercommons.org/js/d3/examples/force/force-multi-foci.html)) and I've been successful in adding in my own data but I haven't been able to specify how many clusters there are and how to assign a node to a cluster.

I'm relatively new to d3 and JavaScript and I haven't been able to find many examples of multi foci applications. Here's my d3 code, any help or input is appreciated:

```
    var width = 960,
    height = 500;

    var fill = d3.scale.category10();


    d3.json("test.json" , function(error, json){

       var root = json.nodes[0];

       root.radius = 0;
       root.fixed = true;  

      var force = d3.layout.force()
         .nodes(json.nodes)
         .size([width, height])
         .gravity(0.06)
         .charge(function(d, i) { return i ? 0 : -2000; })
         .on("tick", tick)
         .start();

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
         .attr("width", width)
         .attr("height", height);

      var elem = svg.selectAll(".elem")
         .data(json.nodes)
         .enter()
         .append("g")
         .attr("class", "elem");

  elem.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("r", 40)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i & 3); })
  .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(fill(i & 3)).darker(2); })
  .call(force.drag)
  .on("mousedown", function() { d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

  elem.append("text")
  .text(function(d){ return d.name; });

  svg.style("opacity", 1e-6)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("opacity", 1);

  d3.select("body")
    .on("mousedown", mousedown);
```

I've specifically been trying to figure out how this tick function is working. I did some research and found that the "&" is a bitwise operator and I noticed that changing the number after it is what is changing how many clusters there are and which nodes are in each. But preferably I would like to be able to point to something like d.group here to specify the cluster.

```
 function tick(e) {

    // Push different nodes in different directions for clustering.
    var k = 6 * e.alpha;
    json.nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {

        o.y += i & 3 ? k : -k;
        o.x += i & 2 ? k : -k;      
    });

 var q = d3.geom.quadtree(json.nodes),
      i = 0,
      n = json.nodes.length;

 while (++i < n) q.visit(collide(json.nodes[i]));

 svg.selectAll("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

 svg.selectAll("text")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
 }

  function collide(node) {
  var r = node.radius + 16,
      nx1 = node.x - r,
      nx2 = node.x + r,
      ny1 = node.y - r,
      ny2 = node.y + r;
  return function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if (quad.point && (quad.point !== node)) {
      var x = node.x - quad.point.x,
          y = node.y - quad.point.y,
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = node.radius + quad.point.radius;
      if (l < r) {
        l = (l - r) / l * .5;
        node.x -= x *= l;
        node.y -= y *= l;
        quad.point.x += x;
        quad.point.y += y;
      }
    }
    return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
  };
}

svg.on("mousemove", function() {
  var p1 = d3.mouse(this);
  root.px = p1[0];
  root.py = p1[1];
  force.resume();
}); 

function mousedown() {
  json.nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
  o.x += (Math.random() - .5) * 40;
  o.y += (Math.random() - .5) * 40;
});

force.resume();
}
});
```

*Note that I have also implemented collision detection to repel nodes but I don't think this is affecting the clusters at the moment.

My data is currently stored in a json file called test.json:

```
 {
  "nodes":[
    {
        "name":     "Null",
        "radius":   40,
        "color":    "#ff0000",
        "gravity": 0.05,
        "group": 1
        },
        {
        "name":     "One",
        "radius":   40,
        "color":    "#ffff00",
        "gravity": 0.05,
        "group": 1
        },
        {
        "name":     "Two",
        "radius":   40,
        "color":    "#33cc33",
        "gravity": 0.2,
        "group": 1
        },
        {
        "name":     "Three",
        "radius":   40,
        "color":    "#3399ff",
        "gravity": 0.9,
        "group": 1
        },
        {
        "name":     "Four",
        "radius":   40,
        "color":    "#ffff00",
        "gravity": 0.05,
        "group": 6
        },
        {
        "name":     "Five",
        "radius":   40,
        "color":    "#33cc33",
        "gravity": 0.2,
        "group": 6
        },
        {
        "name":     "Six",
        "radius":   40,
        "color":    "#3399ff",
        "gravity": 0.9,
        "group": 6
        }             

  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey @codonnell how did my answer work out for you?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply but this was exactly what I needed. The key was nesting the nodes into the groups and then I was able to specify the x and y values for each group with statements like       groups[6].x = 540 and groups[6].y = 750.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the clustering work takes place here:

```
// Push different nodes in different directions for clustering.
var k = 6 * e.alpha;
json.nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
    o.y += i & 3 ? k : -k;
    o.x += i & 2 ? k : -k;      
});
```

Admittedly, I don't get how it works in *this particular* example. It seems indirect and hard to understand. More generally, this is what you want to do in order to cluster:

```
force.on("tick", function(e) {
  var k = e.alpha * .1;
  nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    var center = ...; // here you want to set center to the appropriate [x,y] coords
    node.x += (center.x - node.x) * k;
    node.y += (center.y - node.y) * k;
  });
```

It's taken straight out of [this example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/foci.html) and you can view source to see the code.

In this code, it's easier to understand how, on tick, the nodes are pushed closer to a desired focal point. So now you need to come up with a way to map a node to a focal point based on its `group` param so that you fill in that `var center = ...;` line.

First, you need to get an inventory of all the groups in `json.nodes`. `d3.nest()` is good for that:

```
var groups = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.group; })
  .map(json.nodes)
```

That will give you a mapping of groups to node. Since your example json has just 2 groups in it (`"1"` and `"6"`), it'll look like this:

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "name": "Null",
      "radius": 40,
      "color": "#ff0000",
      "gravity": 0.05,
      "group": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "One",
      "radius": 40,
      "color": "#ffff00",
      "gravity": 0.05,
      "group": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Two",
      "radius": 40,
      "color": "#33cc33",
      "gravity": 0.2,
      "group": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Three",
      "radius": 40,
      "color": "#3399ff",
      "gravity": 0.9,
      "group": 1
    }
  ],
  "6": [
    {
      "name": "Four",
      "radius": 40,
      "color": "#ffff00",
      "gravity": 0.05,
      "group": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "Five",
      "radius": 40,
      "color": "#33cc33",
      "gravity": 0.2,
      "group": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "Six",
      "radius": 40,
      "color": "#3399ff",
      "gravity": 0.9,
      "group": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can loop over `groups` and assign each group a center point as you'd like. How you do that depends on what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps you'd like to distribute the focal points in a circle around the center of the screen. It's up to you... But the goal is to end up with something where `groups["1"].center` equals something like `{x:123, y:456}`, because then you can plug that back into the tick handler from above:

```
force.on("tick", function(e) {
  var k = e.alpha * .1;
  nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    var center = groups[node.group].center;
    node.x += (center.x - node.x) * k;
    node.y += (center.y - node.y) * k;
  });
```

And (hopefully) voila!