# Grouping SVG circles using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have this data :

```
[{"node":"A","group":"1","type":"node"},
 {"node":"B","group":"2","type":"node"},
 {"node":"D","group":"1","type":"node"},
 {"node":"C","group":"2","type":"node"},
 {"type":"link","interest":"1","source":"A","target":"B"},
 {"type":"link","interest":"2","source":"A","target":"C"},
 {"type":"link","interest":"10","source":"B","target":"C"},
 {"type":"link","interest":"3","source":"D","target":"B"}]
```

Here is my code:

```
 var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(data)
    .size([+width(), +height()])
    .gravity(.08)
    .charge(-10)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .on("end", function(){
      chart.dispatchEndDrawing()
    })
    .start();

var g = selection
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


var link = g.selectAll("line")
    .data(data.filter(function (d){ return d.type == "link"; }))
    .enter().append("line")
        .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.interest; })
        .style("stroke", "grey")
        .call(force.drag); 

var node = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data.filter(function (d){ return d.type == "node"; }))
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", "blue")
        .call(force.drag);


function tick(e) {
    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius(), Math.min(width() - radius(), d.x)); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius(), Math.min(height()-10 - radius(), d.y)); });


    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d3.selectAll('circle').filter(function (k) { return d.source === k.node; }).attr('cx');})
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d3.selectAll('circle').filter(function (k) { return d.source === k.node; }).attr('cy'); })   
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d3.selectAll('circle').filter(function (k) { return d.target === k.node; }).attr('cx'); })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d3.selectAll('circle').filter(function (k) { return d.target === k.node; }).attr('cy'); });

         chart.dispatchStartDrawing()

}

})
```

I want to display 4 circles (A, B, C, D) in separate groups: 
Group 1 -  (A,D)   |  Group 2 -  (B,C).

The grouping should be automatic by using the attribute "group".

The simulation is done by creating a d3 force layout object

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022429/create-node-clusters-focal-points-by-data-attribute-in-d3#23023566

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create node cluster's focal points by data attribute in d3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022429/create-node-clusters-focal-points-by-data-attribute-in-d3)